# MySQL compare and delete to large tables ~30m records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I need to find values that exist in table1 but not in table2 and delete those values from table1 (both tables have primary keys). The problem is that the tables are too large and the query like below takes a lot of time:

```
DELETE
FROM table_1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT primarykey FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.primarykey )
```

Is there a way to perform the task in chunks e.g. 300k rows at a time? Or a better optimized solution?

Comment: `where t1.id < 300000 * n`

Comment: You could probably use a `limit` on the subquery so you only get back X records... A join rather than sub query might be faster. I've had issues with subqueries not using indices when subqueried.

Comment: @user3783243 Could you give an example query using join and limits?

Comment: `FROM table_1 t1 join primarykey as p1 t1.id = p1.primarykey`  then remove the `WHERE` I wouldn't think you'd need the `limit` but give that a try and see how it executes. You can use `explain` as well to see what indices are/aren't being used.

Comment: @ITFreak - What percentage of the rows are actually being deleted?  Are the rows to-be-deleted at on 'end' of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete only 1K rows at a time.  Keep in mind that InnoDB needs to hang onto all the deleted rows in case of a crash.  (Then it can `ROLLBACK` the mess.)  If you do delete in chunks, do *not* use `OFFSET`.  Instead, walk through using the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (More details in the link below.)

If you are deleting most of the rows of a table, it is much faster to

```
CREATE TABLE new ...;   -- either say "LIKE real" or spell out schema
INSERT INTO new
    SELECT ... FROM real WHERE opposite-test;
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             new TO real;   -- atomic and fast
DROP TABLE old;   -- after you verify that it worked.
```

More tips on big deletes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig
[*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) also discusses a case of dealing with part of a table, in bulk.

Comment: This is what I needed.... The solution (in the link you mentioned) using loop worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a left join instead of a sub-query; that would be a lot faster. Then you can delete the rows that have a `NULL` value in the join for a field in the joined table that cannot have a `NULL` value.

That would look something like this:

```
DELETE table_1 
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.primarykey
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Is okay to run this query for tables having 30 million records?

Comment: @ITFreak I don't see why not but I guess it depends on the number of rows that will get deleted. Have you tried and timed it?

Comment: @jeroen - building all the `ROLLBACK` stuff for 30M deletes will take a loooong time.

Comment: @RickJames Definitely, but I would assume only a very small part of the 30M records would have to be deleted. Impossible to tell without more information from the OP however.